# Set Where Parameter Dynamically on stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, search

I have a stored procedure to search the data from database with parameter like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rintis_SearchPayment]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @payIDin as int,
    @PayAccountin as varchar(10),
    @PayCustNamein as varchar(30),
    @PayAmountin as int,
    @PayAmountPaidin as int,
    @PayResponsein as char (2),
    @PayRefNoin as varchar (120),
    @PayScreenTextin as varchar (100),
    @PayReceiptTextin as varchar (350),
    @PayDatetimein as datetime,
    @PayBankCodein as varchar (6),

    @payIDou as int,
    @PayAccountou as varchar(10),
    @PayCustNameou as varchar(30),
    @PayAmountou as int,
    @PayAmountPaidou as int,
    @PayResponseou as char (2),
    @PayRefNoou as varchar (120),
    @PayScreenTextou as varchar (100),
    @PayReceiptTextou as varchar (350),
    @PayDatetimeou as datetime,
    @PayBankCodeouin as varchar (6)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    select @payIDou = PayId ,
           @PayAccountou = PayAccount, 
           @PayCustNameou = PayCustName,
           @PayAmountou = PayAmount,
           @PayAmountPaidou = PayAmountPaid,
           @PayResponseou= PayResponse,
           @PayRefNoou= PayRefNo,
           @PayScreenTextou= PayScreenText,
           @PayReceiptTextou= PayReceiptText,
           @PayDatetimeou= PayDatetime,
           @PayBankCodeouin= PayBankCode
    from Payment
    where PayId is not null AND
          PayAccount like '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          PayCustName LIKE '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          PayAmount LIKE '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          PayAmountPaid LIKE '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          PayResponse  LIKE  '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          PayRefNo LIKE '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%' AND
          cast(PayDatetime as date) = ( select convert(date , ''+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'', 103)) order by PayDatetime DESC

    select @payIDou
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
END
```

but when I execute it I didn't give value, cause I know some like statement is incorrect, so it'll never give the return value.

At first I do the query like this on my vb .net :

```
   Public Function SearchPayment(ByVal PayAccount As String, ByVal PayCustName As String, ByVal PayAmount As String, ByVal PayAmountPaid As String, ByVal PayResponse As String, ByVal PayRefNo As String, ByVal PayDatetime As String) As Boolean
        Dim strsql As String = " select top 100 *  from Payment where PayId is not null   "
        If PayAccount <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayAccount like '%" & PayAccount & "%'"
        End If
        If PayCustName <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayCustName like '%" & PayCustName & "%'"
        End If
        If PayAmount <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayAmount like '%" & PayAmount & "%'"
        End If
        '' add PayAmountPaid
        If PayAmountPaid <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayAmountPaid like '%" & PayAmountPaid & "%'"
        End If
        If PayResponse <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayResponse like '%" & PayResponse & "%'"
        End If
        '' add PayRefNo
        If PayRefNo <> "" Then
            strsql &= "and PayRefNo like '%" & PayRefNo & "%'"
        End If
        If PayDatetime <> "" Then
            ''select *  from Inquiry where InquiryId is not null   and cast(InquiryDate as date) = ( select convert(date ,'7/05/2013' ,   103) )
            strsql &= "and cast(PayDatetime as date) = ( select convert(date , '" & PayDatetime & "', 103)) "
        End If
        strsql &= "order by PayDatetime DESC"
        Return runQuery(strsql)

    End Function
```

Is it possible to add `Where` parameter by checking the input value first like I did on my vb.net ?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you set the value of your parameters with `SELECT @payIDou = PayId ....` they are not declared as output parameters so you cannot read them back in your vb code

Comment: @Steve ah pardon me, i made mistake when copy the code, i put the output code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(@PayAccountin IS NULL OR
 PayAccount like '%'+ISNULL((@PayAccountin),'')+'%') AND
```

If the parameter is null it will be true and will ignore the condition

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the stored procedure then the simplest solution would be to add the IS NULL check in the WHERE clause. Somethin like:

```
 select @payIDou = PayId ,
       @PayAccountou = PayAccount, 
       @PayCustNameou = PayCustName,
       @PayAmountou = PayAmount,
       @PayAmountPaidou = PayAmountPaid,
       @PayResponseou= PayResponse,
       @PayRefNoou= PayRefNo,
       @PayScreenTextou= PayScreenText,
       @PayReceiptTextou= PayReceiptText,
       @PayDatetimeou= PayDatetime,
       @PayBankCodeouin= PayBankCode
from Payment
where PayId is not null AND
      ((PayAccount like '%'+ @PayAccountin+'%') OR @PayAccountin IS NULL) AND
      ((PayCustName LIKE '%'+ @PayAccountin+'%') OR @PayAccountin IS NULL) AND... //the rest of your WHERE clause
```

This will effectively ignore the arguments that are passed as NULL.
Hope i understood your question correctly.

Comment: @SabilValdano This WHERE clause itself will return multiple rows. I believe your "only one row returning" problem is caused by another part of code. Could you post a better version of your code? I see from your other comments that this one is pretty mixed up and not really functional.

Answer (score 1):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rintis_SearchPayment]

@payIDin AS INT,
...

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @payIDou = PayId ,
           @PayAccountou = PayAccount, 
           @PayCustNameou = PayCustName,
           @PayAmountou = PayAmount,
           @PayAmountPaidou = PayAmountPaid,
           @PayResponseou= PayResponse,
           @PayRefNoou= PayRefNo,
           @PayScreenTextou= PayScreenText,
           @PayReceiptTextou= PayReceiptText,
           @PayDatetimeou= PayDatetime,
           @PayBankCodeouin= PayBankCode
    FROM dbo.Payment
    WHERE PayId IS NOT NULL
        AND (
            @PayAccountin IS NULL 
            OR 
                (
                         PayAccount LIKE '%' + @PayAccountin + '%'
                    AND PayCustName LIKE '%' + @PayAccountin + '%'
                    AND PayAmount LIKE '%'+ @PayAccountin +'%'
                    AND PayAmountPaid LIKE '%' + @PayAccountin +'%' 
                    AND PayResponse  LIKE  '%'+ @PayAccountin + '%' 
                    AND PayRefNo LIKE '%'+ @PayAccountin + '%' 
                )
        )
        AND (
              @PayAccountin IS NULL 
            OR 
              CAST(PayDatetime AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE , @PayAccountin, 103)
        )
    ORDER BY PayDatetime DESC

    SELECT @payIDou

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You For your Respon, but i found another solution, using `sp_Executesql` and is more effective :

```
Create Procedure SearchPaymentDev



    @PayAccountin as varchar(10),
    @PayCustNamein as varchar(30),
    @PayAmountin as int,
    @PayAmountPaidin as int,
    @PayResponsein as char (2),
    @PayRefNoin as varchar (120),
    @PayScreenTextin as varchar (100),
    @PayReceiptTextin as varchar (350),
    @PayDatetimein as datetime,
    @PayBankCodein as varchar (6),


AS
    Set NoCount ON
    /* Variable Declaration */
    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 
    /* Build the Transact-SQL String with the input parameters */ 
    Set @SQLQuery = 'Select * From payment where PayId is not null  ' 
    /* check for the condition and build the WHERE clause accordingly */
    If @PayAccountin Is Not Null 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAccount = @PayAccountin)'

    If @PayCustNamein Is Not Null
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayCustName = @PayCustNamein)' 

    If @PayAmountin Is Not Null
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAmount = @PayAmountin)'

    If @PayAmountPaidin Is Not Null
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAmountPaid = @PayAmountPaidin)'

    --If (@StartDate Is Not Null) AND (@EndDate Is Not Null)
    --     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (JoiningDate 
    --     BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)'
    /* Specify Parameter Format for all input parameters included 
     in the stmt */
    Set @ParamDefinition =      '@PayAccountin as varchar(10),
                @PayCustNamein as varchar(30),
                @PayAmountin as int,
                @PayAmountPaidin as int'
    /* Execute the Transact-SQL String with all parameter value's 
       Using sp_executesql Command */
    Execute sp_Executesql     @SQLQuery, 
                @ParamDefinition, 
                @PayAccountin, 
                @PayCustNamein, 
                @PayAmountin, 
                @PayAmountPaidin

    If @@ERROR <> 0 GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set NoCount OFF
    Return(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)
GO
```